# Cube to Sphere for smooth texturing

Tags: three.js

my goal is to create a sphere from a cube to apply 6 textures. One for each face. With the old core of three.js this was an easy thing. Here the link what i wish to do with the actual core of three.js.

https://blogg.bekk.no/procedural-planet-in-webgl-and-three-js-fc77f14f5505

The new core make this goal heavier than i thought.
How can i make a sphere from a cube in the new core with smooth textures in the edges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward, as it described in the article provided. Normalize vertices, multiply with desired radius:

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.135.0";
import {OrbitControls} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.135.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.setScalar(10);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

let controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

const r = 7;
let g = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1, 10, 10, 10);
let v = new THREE.Vector3(); // temp vector, for re-use
for(let i = 0; i < g.attributes.position.count; i++){
  v.fromBufferAttribute(g.attributes.position, i);
  v.normalize().multiplyScalar(r); // or v.setLength(r); 
  g.attributes.position.setXYZ(i, v.x, v.y, v.z);
}
g.computeVertexNormals();

let m = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: "aqua", wireframe: true});
let cube = new THREE.Mesh(g, m);
scene.add(cube);

renderer.setAnimationLoop( _ => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Ah ok, i understand the difference. In the new core i have to access the position attribute. It works well. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Spiri You're welcome :) Mark the answer as "accepted", if it solved your question.